# Android: push text view text towards left instead of right

Tags: android, textview

Straight Forward. I am having a text view which will be populated with additional text during run time. When i add new text it is appended, but it shows as "...".

Eg: "Some text in text view..."

What i am trying to achieve is, to display new text and show old text as "..."

Eg: "...This is newly added text at runtime"

Comment: Please post your xml here

Comment: Ankit, kcoppock answer worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TextView, if you're instantiating it via an XML layout, add the ellipsize tag to your TextView:

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```

Which will cause the beginning of the text to be ellipsized, rather than the end.

If you're creating your TextView in code, use:

```
myTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.START);
```